# android studio problema con libreria en implementation de admob y firebase

Tags: android, android-studio, firebase, gradle, admob

hola tengo el siguiente problema ya que tengo un proyecto que estoy trabajando e incluso con un nuevo proyecto al implementar las librerias en android studio la libreria de implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:18.0.0'
 y la libreria de implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.2.0' marca error ya busque un buen de formas y no puedo arreglar ese problema alguien que me pueda ayudar? aparece este error ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': o el error de la foto[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí] si alguien puede checar e implementar estas dos librerias y les compile perfectamente que puedan decirme que esta mal

Comment: Hola, bienvenido a stackoverflow!. No utilices imágenes para poner tu código, ya que dificulta la manipulación para personas que desean ayudarte. Puedes leer [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: hola amigo y deje la captura de pantalla para que fuera mas entendible pero entonces recorto la imagen del error que aparece?

Comment: En la imagen lo que sale es `Connection refused`, no el error que dices en la pregunta. Por favor pon el texto del mensaje de error que te está saliendo. Además actualiza las librerías a la última versión, aquellas librerías que aparecen sombreadas en amarillo indican que hay versiones actualizadas de ellas y convendría que las uses.